# Scala バッチ処理で定期的にDB(MySQL)のデータを確認したい

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework

こんにちは！

Scalaでバッチ処理を実装したいのですが、
用途としてはDBに保存されているデータの日付型を確認し、現在時間がその日付を超えたらある処理を行う、のようにしたいです。

あるいはサーバー側でそのような処理が行えるのなら、それも知りたいです。

Play Framework 2.3.x
Scala 2.11.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

事故解決
onStartで実行時にスケジューラを起動

```
object Global extends GlobalSettings {
override def onStart(app: Application) {

    Logger.info("Application has started for " + app.mode + " mode.")

    val scheduler = QuartzSchedulerExtension(Akka.system)
    scheduler.schedules.foreach {
        case (key, setting) =>
            scheduler.schedule(
                setting.name,
                ${setting.name}"))),
                setting.description.getOrElse(setting.name)
            )
    }

}
```

参考:
http://qiita.com/rynkjm/items/ba356459f8da1d3e0ddf
http://tech.aainc.co.jp/archives/9620